# C array permutations with macros

Tags: c, macros

Is it possible to generate a specific permutation of an array with a macro in C?

i.e. If I have an array X with elements:

```
      0   1   2   3   4   5  
x = ["0","1","1","0","1","0"]
```

I was thinking there may be some macro foo for something like this:

```
#define S_2Permute(x) = [x[5], x[3], x[4], x[2], x[1]]
```

where I redefine the order of the array, so the element in the original position 5 is now in position 0.

Any ideas?

**EXAMPLE USE**

I am starting to create an implementation of the DES encryption algorithm. DES requires several permutation/expansions where I would have to re-order all of the elements in the array, sometimes shrinking the array and sometimes expanding it. I was hoping to just be able to define a macro to permute the arrays for me.

**EDIT2**

Well in DES the first step is something called the initial permutation. So initially I have some 64-bit key, which for this example can be 0-15 hex:

```
0123456789ABCDEF
```

which expands to:

```
0000 0001 0010 0011 0100 0101 0110 0111 1000 1001 1010 1011 1100 1101 1110 1111
```

The IP (initial permutation) would permute this string so that every element in the array would be in a new position:

```
IP = 
            58    50   42    34    26   18    10    2
            60    52   44    36    28   20    12    4
            62    54   46    38    30   22    14    6
            64    56   48    40    32   24    16    8
            57    49   41    33    25   17     9    1
            59    51   43    35    27   19    11    3
            61    53   45    37    29   21    13    5
            63    55   47    39    31   23    15    7
```

So the new 1st element in the bitstring would be the 58th element(bit) from the original bitstring.

So I would have all of these bits stored in an array of characters:

```
x = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,
     1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1]
```

and then just call

```
IP_PERMUTE(x);
```

And macro magic will have moved all of the bits into the new correct positions.

Comment: I'm not sure I get it. Could you provide an example of how you would want to use this?

Comment: @GregHewgill sure, I added what I will hopefully use this for.

Comment: I was thinking more of a code example. How *exactly* would your code look, and which part would the macro replace?

Comment: My guess was the Obfuscated C Contest. Seriously, don't use a macro.

Comment: I would recommend an inline function over a macro (most popular C compilers support an inline keyword), which has the same performance benefits as a macro but is much safer.

Comment: It has to compile in ANSI C, C99 isn't allowed for this project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Absolutely - you're almost there with your example. Try this:

```
 #define S_2Permute(x) {x[5], x[3], x[4], x[2], x[1]}
```

Then later:

```
int x[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
int y[] = S_2Permute(x); // y is now {6,4,5,3,2}
```

Two things to remember:

1) in C, arrays are numbered from 0, so it's possible you meant:

```
#define S_2Permute(x) {x[4], x[2], x[3], x[1], x[0]}
```

2) If you're using gcc, you can compile with `-E` to see the output from the preprocessor (very good for debugging macro expansions).

---

However, I don't think I'd actually do it this way - I'd say the code will be easier to read (and potentially less error prone) if you generate the permutations programmatically - and I doubt that it'll be a large performance hit.

---

Since you say you're having trouble compiling this, here's a test program that works for me in gcc 4.6.1:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define S_2Permute(x) {x[5], x[3], x[4], x[2], x[1]}

int main(void) {
  int x[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
  int y[] = S_2Permute(x);

  for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    printf("%d,",y[i]);
  }
  printf("\n");
}
```

I compiled with `gcc test.c -std=c99 -Wall`

Comment: I get a compiler error when I try this: `MACRO_TEST.c:4:1: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '{' token`

Comment: Really? Can you post your macro and the line you use it on? It works for me in GCC 4.6.1

Comment: Here is the macro: `#define S2_PERMUTE(x)  {x[4], x[2], x[3], x[1], x[0]}` And I call the macro just as you did in your example. I am using gcc 4.5.2. When I run gcc -E however I see that the preprocessor expanded the array correctly. I will post the whole program above.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen I've edited the answer to include a test program that should compile.

Comment: Yours compiled..Weird. But thanks a lot this was very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I'm new so apologies if it's not ok to offer a different means of solution but have you considered using an inline function instead of a macro?

I love single lines of code that do a lot as much as the next guy, but it makes more sense to me to do it this way:

```
//I would have an array that defined how I wanted to swap the positions, I'll assume 5 elements
short reordering[5] = {4,1,3,2,0};

inline void permuteArray(char array[]) {
    char swap = array[reordering[0]];
    array[reordering[0]] = array[reordinger[1]];
    array[reordering[1]] = array[reordinger[2]];
    array[reordering[2]] = array[reordinger[3]];
    array[reordering[3]] = array[reordinger[4]];
    array[reordering[4]] = swap;
}
```

This may not be as pretty or efficient as a macro, but it could save you some headaches managing and maintaining your code (and could always be swapped for the macro version Timothy suggest.

Comment: It's perfectly fine to suggest a different (and better!) solution to any question, as long as it actually solves the problem at hand. You should improve your answer by elaborating on what you meant by "using an inline function", preferably with compilable code samples.

Comment: Thanks for the response, will do.

Answer (score 0):

I am doing something vary similar. This is my code. The variable that comes in is a ulong, so then i convert it to a bit array and then rearrange all the bits and then turn it back into a ulong.

```
public override ulong Permutation(ulong input, int[] permuation)
        {
            byte[] test = BitConverter.GetBytes(input);
            BitArray test2 = new BitArray(test);
            BitArray final = new BitArray(test);
            ulong x = 0;
            ulong y = 1;
            for (int i = 0; i < permuation.Length; i++)
            {
                final[i] = test2[(permuation[i]-1)];
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < final.Length; i++)
            {

                if (final[i] == true)
                {
                    x += (1 * y);
                }
                else
                {
                    x += (0 * y);
                }
                y = y * 2;
            }
            return x;
        }
```